# jQuery validation not working on webforms form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have this in a separated js file

```
$(function () {

    var form = $("#formNovoArtigo").validate({
        rules: {
            '[id*=txtCadenciaMensal]': {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "[id*=txtCadenciaMensal]": "Insira a Cadência Mensal"
        },
    });    
});
```

however i even tried to see what's going on with a try catch but it won't trigger so I'm not sure what am i doing wrong. I added rule to a textbox to accept only numbers but nothing happens. no message not nothing

Edit.

Here's scripts references

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/adminlte").Include(
            "~/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.js",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/js").Include(
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/menu-selection.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/DataTables.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/Validation.js"));
```

Comment: what libraries  are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery validation that comes with jquery from nuget package on VS2013, there's no error on console about plugins. I edited my post shwing all scripts i'm using

Comment: u should use name of input fields instead of id. e.g: `<input name="salary" />` then your rule look like this `salary: { ... }`.

Comment: for testing purpose use `jQuery.validators.setDefaults` as shown in this [link](https://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/). this will display your configuration errors.

Comment: Well now it worked... Seriously I don't know what was wrong. Because I'm using ASP net webforms I installed xVal.WebForms and just made a model and when I submitted the jquery error message on client side appeared...

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found the error, i forgot to write input before the ID... Works 100% in ASP.NET 4.5

```
$(function () {

    $('form').validate({
        debug:true
    });
        $('input[id*=txtCadenciaMensal]').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'Some custom message for the username required field'
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: (y), this would be helpful to those who want to add dynamic rules.